# Issue in Bluetooth Discovery Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm pretty sure there's at least two devices disoverable with bluetooth but my application just show me paired one. I already gived bluetooth permission and i don't understand where is the problem. Can you find it?

```
//Scan Function
void startScan(){

    adapter.clear();                                    //List View cleared
    deviceList = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();          //Paired Device
    for (BluetoothDevice bd : deviceList)               //Adding Paired Device
        adapter.add(bd.getName() + "\n" + bd.getAddress()+"\t (Paired)");

    //Init of Broadcast Receiver
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action  = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){        //Device Found
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);   //Extractind Device Info
                adapter.add(device.getName()+"\t"+device.getAddress());                             //Adding Device to List View
            }
        }
    };

    //Broadcast Receiver Registration
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
    btAdapter.startDiscovery();                         //Scan start

}
```

Comment: and where are you starting your discovering of bluetooth devices? using `btAdapter.startDiscovery();`?

Comment: yes, it shoul work in this way

Comment: Are you running marshmallow? It requires location permissions and location services enabled to start detecting devices.

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong you are getting only bonded device. Your code should be something like below.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
void startScan(){
adapter.clear();                                    //List View cleared
deviceList = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();          //Paired Device
for (BluetoothDevice bd : deviceList)               //Adding Paired Device
    adapter.add(bd.getName() + "\n" + bd.getAddress()+"\t (Paired)");
//Broadcast Receiver Registration
```

Check for bluetooth enable

```
(!btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent BtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(BtIntent, 0);
        Toast.makeText(BluetoothScannerActivity.this, "Turning on Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 else{
registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
btAdapter.startDiscovery();                         //Scan start
}
}
```

Your broadcast should be out of method, its better parctice

```
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action  = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){        //Device Found
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);   //Extractind Device Info
            adapter.add(device.getName()+"\t"+device.getAddress());                             //Adding Device to List View
        }
    }
};

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == BtIntent && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
    btAdapter.startDiscovery(); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: my function is external from the program flow, i aready do the check about    bluetooth status (and it works so i'm sure is enabled). However what should change from mine e your implementation? It's seems they do same things so where's the problem in mine?